# ElasticBeanstalk: Run simple node.js server and smtp server simultaneously

Tags: nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm using Elastic Beanstalk (node.js / nginx) to build a simple inbound email relay that will receive email and push the content of the email to an SQS queue. I'm using the "mailin" package to facilitate an inbound smtp service and have another simple node http service that serves "ok" for the health check at /.

I'm able to start both services, but I'm unable to send email to the mailin service because port 25 isn't open. Do to needing root/admin privileges to use low numbered ports, I'm now starting this service on port 2025. I've attempted to then open that port both as a listener on the load balancer as well as forward port 25 traffic to port 2025.

I've stopped the built-in sendmail service in eb.config and created a proxy.config in .ebextensions to specify mailin as an upstram server at port 2025 and for the instance to proxy traffic to it, but with no results. I'm stumped.

**eb.config**

```html
commands:
  01_install_termcolor:
    command: 'easy_install termcolor'
  02_stop_sendmail:
    command: '/etc/init.d/sendmail stop'
```

**proxy.config**

```html
files:
  /etc/nginx/conf.d/mailproxy.conf:
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      upstream mailin {
        server 127.0.0.1:2025;
        keepalive 256;
      }
      server {
        listen 25;
        location / {
            proxy_pass  http://mailin;
            proxy_set_header   Connection "";
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
      }
```

**App.js**

```js
var mailin = require('mailin');
var fs = require('fs');
var aws = require('aws-sdk');

aws.config.update({
  region: process.env.AWS_REGION || 'us-east-1',
  accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY ,
  secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_SECRET
})


mailin.start({
  port: 2025,
  logFile: 'log.txt',
  logLevel: 'info', // One of silly, info, debug, warn, error
  disableWebhook: true // Disable the webhook posting.
});
/* Event emitted after a message was received and parsed. */
mailin.on('message', function (connection, data, content) {
  console.log(data);
   var sqs = new aws.SQS();
  sqs.sendMessage({
    MessageBody: "testing!",
    QueueUrl: process.env.QueueURL || 'https://...'
  }, function(err, data){
    console.log(err)
    console.log(data)
    return
  })

});


// content of index.js
const http = require('http')  
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const url = require('url');

const requestHandler = (request, response) => {  
  response.end("OK");
}

const server = http.createServer(requestHandler)

server.listen(port, (err) => {  
  if (err) {
    return console.log('something bad happened', err)
  }

  console.log(`server is listening on ${port}`)
})
```